# JSF Resources Doesnt Cache PNG Files

Tags: jsf, caching, resources, png

For some reason JSF doesn't set the headers on PNG files but it does on JPG files.
e.g. https://www.medexpress.co.uk/

All images are using graphicImage. e.g.

```
<h:graphicImage library="img" name="logos/medexpress-logo.png" alt="MedExpress UK" />
```

logos.jpg.xhtml?ln=img (not missing cache headers)

```
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:7694
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Mon, 11 Jan 2016 01:22:50 GMT
ETag:W/"7890-1448193800000"
Expires:Wed, 17 Feb 2016 08:11:29 GMT
Last-Modified:Sun, 22 Nov 2015 12:03:20 GMT
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

medexpress.png.xhtml?ln=img (Missing cache headers)

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Date:Mon, 11 Jan 2016 01:31:17 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: Resources filter? You mean, you have some custom servlet filter which does something with JSF resources? Anyway, you unfortunately omitted the response status code (200, 304, 404, 500, etc), but the PNG response is much similar to ones in a 304 "Not Modified" response. A 304 basically tells the webbrowser to continue using the one in its cache. If you lookup the associated request, you must see a `If-Modified-Since` conditional header. Clean the browser cache or spawn an incognito window to compare. You'll see they will become 200 again for once.

Comment: I've amended the question. I'm not using any custom filter. I expected JSF to add the ETag and Expires headers to the png file. Any reason why it is not doing that?

Comment: I can see the PNG files are being served with 304. I don't really understand why they are being served differently though.

Comment: 304 (and grayed out 200 with size="from cache") means it's cached. I checked your URL for JPEGs and I observe same behavior. So I still don't understand your concrete problem.